# transmission does not create functional torrent

Tags: transmission

I am trying to share a file with a colleague by creating a torrent via transmission.  Testing locally however doesn't seem to work.

I'm testing this on my home network, from which it is known that I can both download and upload torrents.

I have two laptops set up, both running ubuntu.

On machine1, I open transmission...
File...
New...
Source File = blah.jpg
Trackers = The four trackers listed on openbittorrent.com
Click on New, wait for creation, click on Add
Email blah.jpg.torrent to myself

I can now see it in my open transmission client.

On machine2, I open transmission...
Get blah.jpg.torrent from my email
open in transmission.

Inspecting the trackers on each machine,
machine1 shows 1 seeder, 0 leechers
machine2 shows 0 seeders, 1 leecher

Presumably they are seeing themselves via the trackers.
No download, no upload, just sadness.

I right-click and "ask tracker for more peers"... Nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: leave the client-torrent running overnight, see if it ever downloads any data.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl.  The hope was to be like "hey can I have this 10gb file?", "yah sure let me put it in a torrent" ... *10 minutes later* "k thanks"